# AWS CDK Stack is deployed silently even if not explicitly specified

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I have multi stacks CDK setup, the core stack contains the VPC and EKS. The "Tenant" stack that deploys some s3 buckets and k8s namespaces and some other tenant related deployments.

`cdk ls` is displaying all the existing stacks as expected.

```sh
- eks-stack
- tenant-a
- tenant-b
```

If I want to deploy only a single tenant stack, I run `cdk deploy tenant-a`.  To my surprise, I see that in my k8s cluster, the manifest of `tenant-1` and `tenant-b` were deployed, and not just `tenant-a` as I expected.

The CDK output on the CLI correctly outputs that `tenant-a` was deployed. The CLI output doesn't mention ⁣`tenant-b`. I also see that most of the changes did happen inside the eks stack and not in the tenant stack, as I am using the references.

```py
# app.py
# ...
# EKS
efs_stack = EksStack(
    app,
    "eks-stack",
    stack_log_level="INFO",
)


# Tenant Specific stacks
tenants = ['tenant-a', 'tenant-b']  

for tenant in tenants:
    tenant_stack = TenantStack(
        app,
        f"tenant-stack-{tenant}",
        stack_log_level="INFO",
        cluster=eks_cluster_stack.eks_cluster,
        tenant=tenant,
    )
--
#
# Inside TenantStack.py a manifest is applied to k8s 
self.cluster.add_manifest(f'db-job-{self.tenant}', {
            "apiVersion": 'v1',
            "kind": 'Pod',
            "metadata": {"name": 'mypod'},
            "spec": {
                "serviceAccountName": "bootstrap-db-job-access-ssm",
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": 'hello',
                        "image": 'amazon/aws-cli',
                        "command": 'magic stuff ....'
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
```

I found out that when I import a cluster by its attributes and by reference
eg.

```py
self.cluster = Cluster.from_cluster_attributes(  
  self, 'cluster', cluster_name=cluster,  
  open_id_connect_provider=eks_open_id_connect_provider,  
  kubectl_role_arn=kubectl_role
```

I can deploy tenant stack `a` and `b` separately and my core `eks` stack stays untouched. Now I have read It's recommended to use references as CDK can automatically can create dependencies and detect circular dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option to exclude dependencies. Use `cdk deploy tenant-a --exclusively` to don't deploy dependencies.